# what are the options i have to write smtp client in c++ ( cross platform)

Tags: c++, smtp

i need to add the ability in my application to send emails ( with the user's email server/service ) for that i need to wirth or to use smtp c++ lib or code 
in which i have no idea where to find . where can i find free lib or source code that i can use or learn from .
can you please help me on this subject 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using poco c++ libraries. These are resleased under [Boost Software License](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt) (one of the most non-restrictive open source licenses) and they feature Mail-lib as part of it. This is what their doc states:

> Classes for sending e-mail messages via SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, RFC 2821) servers with support for e-mail attachments, as well as classes for downloading e-mail messages from POP3 (Post Office Protocol Version 3, RFC 1939) servers.

[Poco Website](http://pocoproject.org/)

Regards,
Ovanes

P.S. Poco C++ Libs is a multi-platform framework.

Answer (score 1):

Under Unix, the normal way of sending a mail from a program is piping its contain (with popen) to /usr/lib/sendmail.  The other MTAs (postfix and so on) provide a compatibility program with that interface.

The advantage is that you don't have to configure each program sending mail so that they are using the right gateway, able to use aliases, ...

Answer (score 1):

Use boost::asio and follow the protocol specs to write a simple client.

Comment: to much time for that .. 
i relay need cross platform lib , by the way isnt its just protocol so the code can be one for each OS..no?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a GPL license you can try [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/)

and if you want the library for windows you can try [CPJNSMTPConnection](http://www.naughter.com/smtp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) might be an option.
It's a free open-source framework which is available for a lot of operating systems.

I don't know if they have a concrete implementation for smtp but at least they provide C++ abstractions for the connectivity part. So only the protocol implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my c++ smtp client example: https://github.com/breakermind/SslSMTPClient with attachments and allow get mx hosts from recipient email domain automaticaly and you don't need own smtp server:

```
// main - create SSL context and connect
int main(int count, char *strings[])
{ 
    cout << "C++ ssl smtp send email with STARTTLS\r\n";    

    // Add attachments to message if you want
    vector<string> files;
    // files.push_back("file9.jpg");
    // files.push_back("filek.pdf");

    // Initialize
    sslsmtpEx sm;
    sm.sslsmtpExSet("localhost", 25); 

    // EHLO hostname
    sm.heloHostname("domain.pl");

    // Display logs
    // sm.showLogs();

    // get MX records from dns for recipient
    vector<string> mx = sm.getMX("email@gmail.com",0,0);

    // Send email to each mx host from recipient domain DNS ( You need send only to one server !!! )
    for (int i = 0; i < mx.size(); i++){

        // Set hostname from mx dns
        sm.sslsmtpExSet(mx.at(i), 25);
        cout << "Mx host: " << mx.at(i) << endl;    

        // send email
        int ok = sm.Send("email@domain.pl", "nanomoow@gmail.com", "email@domain.pl", "Smtp client test", "<h1>Smtp test</h1>", "<h1>Smtp test</h1>", files);

        cout << "Email has been sent : " <<  ok << endl;

        if(ok){
            // if email has been sent, end loop with next mxhost
            break;
        }            
    }
    sleep(10);

return 0;    
}
```

Regards